# Could not open a file in append or write mode

Tags: c, windows, permissions, fopen

I have a problem by using my program written in ANSI C.
When trying to open a file(file pointer called fp),called 0.dat, in read mode, i can access it without problem. Then I fclose fp. When trying to open fp again using fopen in mode w or a+ it give me "permission denied" using perror.
I can't get why, I tried to open in a+ firstly but it still gives me this permission error.

I am running Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10.
Tried to do a Visual Studio reset but it still didn't work.
Here's a minimal example:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    if ((fp = fopen("1.txt", "w")) == NULL) { perror("error"); exit(1); }
    fprintf(fp, "You smell");
    return 0;
}
```

> Output: error: Permission denied.

Comment: Please [edit] your question, and provide [mcve].

Comment: I've just done it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

check the rights of write to the file which you want to open with the write option with your code.
`if ((fp = fopen("1.txt", "w")) == NULL)`
 the "1.txt" file have to have the write rights.

Answer (score 1):

> [...] using fopen in mode w or a+ it give me "permission denied". I can't get why, I tried to open in a+ firstly but it still gives me this permission error.

The user you run the program under does not seem to have write-access to the file in question.

To *successfully* open a file in write and/or append mode the user running the program needs to have write-access to it.

To get around the issue you are facing,

- either adjust the access rights
- or run the program under a user having been granted write access to the file.

Comment: Hello @alk, my account is administrator I mean I should have write-access to my "Documents" folder in windows,which is the folder the project is into.

Comment: @absentio: Windows' file locking is special; perhaps another process has the file already exclusively open for writing?

Comment: I don't think so. If I remember well, the "w" should create a file it that does not exist. But here fopen don't create anything. Maybe should I just install Ubuntu and say goodbye to Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe disabling antivirus would do the trick. I was having the same issue until I disabled my antivirus (Avast).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).